# Using custom script inside .profile file in ksh

Tags: shell, alias, sh, .profile

I am trying to use a script that takes in some parameters inside my .profile file. The script is basically to execute a particular operation(from a set) on a list of jobs. So I execute the script like this.

```
sh bulkCommandProcessor.sh commandName job1 job2 job3...
```

Since the number of commands that can go in as the first argument is only 7, I would like to have aliases for each of it in my .profile file. I tried the following.

```
alias bjr='sh /home/vijay/scripts/bulkCommandProcessor.sh jr'
```

However, this doesnt seem to work. The error handling part of my code gets displayed when I source the .profile file which says something like this.

```
usage: /home/vijay/scripts/bulkCommandProcessor.sh cmd Job_name1 Job_name2 Job_name3 ..
```

Is there a way to achieve what I intend? That is use a script that accepts variable length of arguments within the .profile file.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you need to make sure that your script *bulkCommandProcesor.sh* has the right permissions, that it is in the right path and that your are correctly parsing arguments for your script. I think that the following template might work:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh
    # .profile example


    alias bjr='sh /home/vijay/scripts/bulkCommandProcessor.sh jr'

    #variable length arguments in jobs 
    #where you previously get job1,job2 for example

    jobs="$job1 $job2"

    #And finally calling your script
    bjr $jobs
```